# The Banach–Tarski Paradox

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

The Banach–Tarski paradox states that, given a ball in 3‑dimensional space, you can decompose the ball into a finite number of point subsets. These disjoint sets of points can then be reassembled to produce two copies of the initial ball. You would then, theoretically, have two identical balls.

The process of reassembly consists of only moving the aforementioned point subsets and rotating them, while not changing their spacial shape. This can be done with as few as five disjoint subsets.

Disjoint sets have no common elements by definition. Where `A` and `B` are any two point subsets of the initial ball, the common elements between `A` and `B` is an empty set. This is shown in the following equation.

[image: LaTeX representation]

For the disjoint sets below, the common members form an empty set.

[image: LaTeX representation]

---

## The Challenge

Write a program that can take an input ASCII "ball", and output a duplicate "ball".

---

## Input

Here is an example input ball:

```
      ##########      
   ###@%$*.&.%%!###   
  ##!$,%&?,?*?.*@!##  
 ##&**!,$%$@@?@*@&&## 
#@&$?@!%$*%,.?@?.@&@,#
#,..,.$&*?!$$@%%,**&&#
 ##.!?@*.%?!*&$!%&?## 
  ##!&?$?&.!,?!&!%##  
   ###,@$*&@*,%*###   
      ##########
```

Each sphere is outlined by pound signs (`#`) and filled with any of theses characters: `.,?*&$@!%`. Every input will be a 22x10 characters (width by height).

---

## Creating a Duplicate

First, each point inside the ball is given a numbered point based on its index in `.,?*&$@!%`. Here is the above example, once numbered:

```
      ##########      
   ###7964151998###   
  ##86295323431478##  
 ##5448269677374755## 
#75637896492137317572#
#21121654386679924455#
 ##1837419384568953## 
  ##85363518238589##  
   ###2764574294###   
      ##########
```

Then, each point is shifted up one (nine goes to one):

```
      ##########      
   ###8175262119###   
  ##97316434542589##  
 ##6559371788485866## 
#86748917513248428683#
#32232765497781135566#
 ##2948521495679164## 
  ##96474629349691##  
   ###3875685315###   
      ##########
```

Finally, each new point value is converted back to its corresponding character:

```
      ##########      
   ###!.@&,$,..%###   
  ##%@?.$*?*&*,&!%##  
 ##$&&%?@.@!!*!&!$$## 
#!$@*!%.@&.?,*!*,!$!?#
#?,,?,@$&*%@@!..?&&$$#
 ##,%*!&,.*%&$@%.$*## 
  ##%$*@*$,%?*%$%.##  
   ###?!@&$!&?.&###   
      ##########
```

---

## Output

These two balls are then output side-by-side, in this form (separated by four spaces at the equators):

```
      ##########                ##########      
   ###@%$*.&.%%!###          ###!.@&,$,..%###   
  ##!$,%&?,?*?.*@!##        ##%@?.$*?*&*,&!%##  
 ##&**!,$%$@@?@*@&&##      ##$&&%?@.@!!*!&!$$## 
#@&$?@!%$*%,.?@?.@&@,#    #!$@*!%.@&.?,*!*,!$!?#
#,..,.$&*?!$$@%%,**&&#    #?,,?,@$&*%@@!..?&&$$#
 ##.!?@*.%?!*&$!%&?##      ##,%*!&,.*%&$@%.$*## 
  ##!&?$?&.!,?!&!%##        ##%$*@*$,%?*%$%.##  
   ###,@$*&@*,%*###          ###?!@&$!&?.&###   
      ##########                ##########
```

---

<sup>Note: Shifting the point values, and later characters, is symbolic of the rotations performed to reassemble the point subsets (character groupings).</sup>

Comment: Does it have to be adjacent? can they be outputed above each others?

Comment: They must be adjacent. The two 22x10 blocks should be horizontally separated by 4 spaces. @Mhmd

Comment: Functions are allowed in your program. The program must execute on its own, though (with a user input). @ETHproductions

Comment: Shouldn't both balls be rotated? As I understand the theorem, the original doesn't stay, but you get two new balls.

Comment: Yes, but an answer had been submitted before I got the chance to make that edit, and I didn't want to invalidate any solutions. @PaŭloEbermann

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Pyth, 21 bytes

```
#++Jw*4d.rJ".,?*&$@!%
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%23%2B%2BJw*4d.rJ%22.%2C%3F*%26%24%40!%25&input=++++++%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23++++++%0A+++%23%23%23%40%25%24*.%26.%25%25!%23%23%23+++%0A++%23%23!%24%2C%25%26%3F%2C%3F*%3F.*%40!%23%23++%0A+%23%23%26**!%2C%24%25%24%40%40%3F%40*%40%26%26%23%23+%0A%23%40%26%24%3F%40!%25%24*%25%2C.%3F%40%3F.%40%26%40%2C%23%0A%23%2C..%2C.%24%26*%3F!%24%24%40%25%25%2C**%26%26%23%0A+%23%23.!%3F%40*.%25%3F!*%26%24!%25%26%3F%23%23+%0A++%23%23!%26%3F%24%3F%26.!%2C%3F!%26!%25%23%23++%0A+++%23%23%23%2C%40%24*%26%40*%2C%25*%23%23%23+++%0A++++++%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23++++++&debug=0)

Finally a use-case for `.r`.

#### Explanation

```
#++Jw*4d.rJ".,?*&$@!%
#                       infinite loop
   Jw                   read a string from input and store it in J
     *4d                4 spaces
        .rJ".,?*&$@!%   rotate the chars of J using this char order
 ++                     combine the 3 strings (J, spaces, rotated) and print
```

The infinite loop breaks, when there is no more input available.

Answer (score 6):

## Matlab, 120

Matlab is not the greatest language for handling strings. `\n` is always considered as two characters, which is quite annoying, and you cannot just make a matrix out of a line-breaked (line-broken?) string, you have to do it manually. At least I did not have to care about the size/padding as every line has the exact same length.

```
a='.,?*&$@!%.';b=input('');b(b>90)=[];b=reshape(b',22,10)';c=b;for k=1:9;c(b==a(k))=a(k+1);end;disp([b,ones(10,4)*32,c])
```

Example Input:

```
'      ##########      \n   ###@%$*.&.%%!###   \n  ##!$,%&?,?*?.*@!##  \n ##&**!,$%$@@?@*@&&## \n#@&$?@!%$*%,.?@?.@&@,#\n#,..,.$&*?!$$@%%,**&&#\n ##.!?@*.%?!*&$!%&?## \n  ##!&?$?&.!,?!&!%##  \n   ###,@$*&@*,%*###   \n      ##########      '
```

Example output:

```
      ##########                ##########      
   ###@%$*.&.%%!###          ###!.@&,$,..%###   
  ##!$,%&?,?*?.*@!##        ##%@?.$*?*&*,&!%##  
 ##&**!,$%$@@?@*@&&##      ##$&&%?@.@!!*!&!$$## 
#@&$?@!%$*%,.?@?.@&@,#    #!$@*!%.@&.?,*!*,!$!?#
#,..,.$&*?!$$@%%,**&&#    #?,,?,@$&*%@@!..?&&$$#
 ##.!?@*.%?!*&$!%&?##      ##,%*!&,.*%&$@%.$*## 
  ##!&?$?&.!,?!&!%##        ##%$*@*$,%?*%$%.##  
   ###,@$*&@*,%*###          ###?!@&$!&?.&###   
      ##########                ##########
```

PS: If I can assume the input this way:

```
['      ##########      ','   ###@%$*.&.%%!###   ','  ##!$,%&?,?*?.*@!##  ',' ##&**!,$%$@@?@*@&&## \n#@&$?@!%$*%,.?@?.@&@,#','#,..,.$&*?!$$@%%,**&&#',' ##.!?@*.%?!*&$!%&?## ','  ##!&?$?&.!,?!&!%##  ','   ###,@$*&@*,%*###   ','      ##########      ']
```

I only need 88 characters:

```
a='.,?*&$@!%.';b=input('');c=b;for k=1:9;c(b==a(k))=a(k+1);end;disp([b,ones(10,4)*32,c])
```

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby, 65

```
10.times{b=gets;puts b.chop.tr(',?*&$@!%.','.,?*&$@!%')+'    '+b}
```

Works great when input is taken from a file instead of stdin:

```
ruby banach.rb < ball.txt
```

On the other hand, if you like typing in balls to stdin manually, and want the output at the end, try this 67-byte version:

```
puts (0..9).map{b=gets;b.chop.tr(',?*&$@!%.','.,?*&$@!%')+'    '+b}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby, 102

```ruby
IO.readlines(?a).map(&:chomp).each{|x|puts"#{x+' '*x.count(' ')+?\s*4+x.tr('.,?*&$@!%',',?*&$@!%.')}"}
```

Basically, its just calling `tr` on the input

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3.5, <s>96</s> <s>89</s> 88 bytes

```
s='.,?*&$@!%.  ##';i=1
while i:i=input();print(i,'  ',''.join(s[s.find(y)+1]for y in i))
```

## Python 3.3, <s>103</s> <s>96</s> 95 bytes

```
s='.,?*&$@!%.  ##'
for i in input().split('\n'):print(i,'  ',''.join(s[s.find(y)+1]for y in i))
```

### Explanation

Python 3.3 and 3.5 are listed separately because the way `input()` handles newlines ***in IDLE*** changed. This happened to save 8 bytes, which is cool.

**Note on execution: use IDLE.** If you use a terminal, then the solution for 3.3 is the same as 3.5, but both interleave the input with the output.

I reversed the symbol string `s` to take advantage of Python's negative indexing. Then for each line in the input, I output it, two spaces, and the line with each symbol replaced with its preceding symbol. The reason I only put two spaces is that I used `,` instead of `+`, which adds a space to the printed output. This (`,'  ',`) saved me a byte over `+' '*4+`.

**Thanks to xsot** for saving me <s>7</s> 8 bytes. I changed `s.find` to `s.rfind` to allow me to put the spaces and hashes into `s`, thereby removing the need to do a check for `y in s`. Plus, a space was saved. EDIT: changed back to `s.find` because the presence of `##` now allows me to `+1` without worrying about an index-out-of-bounds error.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how `input()` changed?  I can't find any differences between the [3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#input) and [3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#input) documentation.

Comment: Newlines in the input string "terminate" the input, so to speak, and re-call your input code. In Python 3.3, newlines are passed in intact. The change must be between 3.3 and 3.4.

Comment: Nope, the [3.3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#input) are the same too.  I'm guessing this is a readline change, probably from a version bump.  If you compile without readline, you might not notice any difference.

Comment: I use IDLE, so it may also be at fault. I'll try running it from a terminal.

Comment: @Kevin: How interesting. From the command line, it works properly in 3.5 although the input is *interleaved* with the output. For 3.3, it breaks immediately after the first newline. I copy-pasted the text whole.

Comment: You don't have to check for spaces or hashes if `s` is `'%!@$&*?,  ##,.'`. Also, you can drop the space before the second `for`.

Comment: @xsot: Thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize that the string I gave you was wrong. Actually, you can use `find` if you increment the index instead, saving a byte.

Comment: @xsot: Ah yes, you're right! That's only possible because the space and hash are included now.

Answer (score 4):

## sed (39 bytes)

```
h;y/.,?*&$@!%/,?*&$@!%./;H;x;s/\n/    /
```

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 28 bytes

```
qN/{_".,?*&$@!%"_(+erS4*\N}%
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B_%22.%2C%3F*%26%24%40!%25%22_(%2BerS4*%5CN%7D%25&input=%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%23%23%23%40%25%24*.%26.%25%25!%23%23%23%20%20%20%0A%20%20%23%23!%24%2C%25%26%3F%2C%3F*%3F.*%40!%23%23%20%20%0A%20%23%23%26**!%2C%24%25%24%40%40%3F%40*%40%26%26%23%23%20%0A%23%40%26%24%3F%40!%25%24*%25%2C.%3F%40%3F.%40%26%40%2C%23%0A%23%2C..%2C.%24%26*%3F!%24%24%40%25%25%2C**%26%26%23%0A%20%23%23.!%3F%40*.%25%3F!*%26%24!%25%26%3F%23%23%20%0A%20%20%23%23!%26%3F%24%3F%26.!%2C%3F!%26!%25%23%23%20%20%0A%20%20%20%23%23%23%2C%40%24*%26%40*%2C%25*%23%23%23%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%20%20%20%20%20%20)

Explanation:

```
qN/     Get input and split into lines.
{       Start loop over lines.
  _       Copy, since we need to output original.
  ".,?*&$@!%"
          List of characters, in order.
  _       Copy list of characters.
  (+      Rotate the list by popping first character and appending it.
  er      Transliterate.
  S4*     Create 4 spaces.
  \       Swap spaces between original and transliteration.
  N       Add newline.
}%      End of loop over lines.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>45</s> 39 bytes

```
.+
$0  ; $0
T`.,?*&$@!%;`,?*&$@!%. `;.*
```

To run the code from a single file, use the `-s` flag.

The first stage duplicates each line, separated by `"  ; "`, to get

```
      ##########        ;       ##########
   ###@%$*.&.%%!###     ;    ###@%$*.&.%%!###
  ##!$,%&?,?*?.*@!##    ;   ##!$,%&?,?*?.*@!##
 ##&**!,$%$@@?@*@&&##   ;  ##&**!,$%$@@?@*@&&##
#@&$?@!%$*%,.?@?.@&@,#  ; #@&$?@!%$*%,.?@?.@&@,#
#,..,.$&*?!$$@%%,**&&#  ; #,..,.$&*?!$$@%%,**&&#
 ##.!?@*.%?!*&$!%&?##   ;  ##.!?@*.%?!*&$!%&?##
  ##!&?$?&.!,?!&!%##    ;   ##!&?$?&.!,?!&!%##
   ###,@$*&@*,%*###     ;    ###,@$*&@*,%*###
      ##########        ;       ##########
```

Then the second stage only affects characters which are found in matches of `;.*`, i.e. only the second half of each line. Those characters are then transliterated via the following correspondence

```
.,?*&$@!%;
,?*&$@!%.
```

Where the first 9 pairs "increment" the characters in the ball and the last pair turns the semicolon into another space.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `ja`, 22 bytes

```
ƛ:`.,?*&$@!%`:ǓĿð4*$++
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=ja&code=%C6%9B%3A%60.%2C%3F*%26%24%40!%25%60%3A%C7%93%C4%BF%C3%B04*%24%2B%2B&inputs=%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%23%23%23%40%25%24*.%26.%25%25!%23%23%23%20%20%20%0A%20%20%23%23!%24%2C%25%26%3F%2C%3F*%3F.*%40!%23%23%20%20%0A%20%23%23%26**!%2C%24%25%24%40%40%3F%40*%40%26%26%23%23%20%0A%23%40%26%24%3F%40!%25%24*%25%2C.%3F%40%3F.%40%26%40%2C%23%0A%23%2C..%2C.%24%26*%3F!%24%24%40%25%25%2C**%26%26%23%0A%20%23%23.!%3F%40*.%25%3F!*%26%24!%25%26%3F%23%23%20%0A%20%20%23%23!%26%3F%24%3F%26.!%2C%3F!%26!%25%23%23%20%20%0A%20%20%20%23%23%23%2C%40%24*%26%40*%2C%25*%23%23%23%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%20%20%20%20%20%20&header=&footer=)

`a` flag makes Vyxal take all newline-separated inputs as a list.

```
ƛ                      # Map...
 `.,?*&$@!%`           # The characters
            :ǓĿ        # Transliterate input by chars and chars shifted
               ?ð4*+   # Add four spaces to each line of the original
                    $+ # Add the previous, with chars shifted
```

-1 thanks to Razetime

Comment: -1: ƛ:\`.,?*&$@!%\`:ǓĿð4*$++

Comment: @Razetime Nice!'

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 77 bytes

```
while 1:r=raw_input();print r,'  ',r.translate(' % #@.$   & ? , '*3+'!*'*104)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 59 bytes

**56 bytes code plus 3 bytes for `-p` as this needs to be saved to a file.**

```pl
chop($s=$_);$l=',?*&$@!%';eval"y/.$l/$l./";$_="$s    $_"
```

Example usage:

```sh
$perl -p ball.pl <<< '      ##########      
>    ###@%$*.&.%%!###   
>   ##!$,%&?,?*?.*@!##  
>  ##&**!,$%$@@?@*@&&## 
> #@&$?@!%$*%,.?@?.@&@,#
> #,..,.$&*?!$$@%%,**&&#
>  ##.!?@*.%?!*&$!%&?## 
>   ##!&?$?&.!,?!&!%##  
>    ###,@$*&@*,%*###   
>       ##########      
> '
      ##########                ##########      
   ###@%$*.&.%%!###          ###!.@&,$,..%###   
  ##!$,%&?,?*?.*@!##        ##%@?.$*?*&*,&!%##  
 ##&**!,$%$@@?@*@&&##      ##$&&%?@.@!!*!&!$$## 
#@&$?@!%$*%,.?@?.@&@,#    #!$@*!%.@&.?,*!*,!$!?#
#,..,.$&*?!$$@%%,**&&#    #?,,?,@$&*%@@!..?&&$$#
 ##.!?@*.%?!*&$!%&?##      ##,%*!&,.*%&$@%.$*## 
  ##!&?$?&.!,?!&!%##        ##%$*@*$,%?*%$%.##  
   ###,@$*&@*,%*###          ###?!@&$!&?.&###   
      ##########                ##########
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
|ʒD4ú".,?*&$@!%"DÀ‡«,
```

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E, because it was possible to use the filter `ʒ` with implicit `y` as a foreach to print, whereas with the new version the actual for-each loop  `v` with explicit `y` should be used, which is 1 byte longer.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bY8xDgJBCEX7OYXsAAUhRBOtodiLaOItLPYM3sDaG1i6ncfwIiOzm2wlHQ/4/7M/nS@Ha2u3z308zq/B1IUxgIZxnr7T4/3U1nZL1a3WvqwsCMXYiGCdlE4BldhTy00COi9JWQQUCSM8JJiTlxqMnn4opObhFhxaS1UzNWRxQAwiFcn9LmKQx0YOmRPSpIssluzobKAODLRaLgE1UDhESbaA/975AQ)

**Explanation:**

```python
|                      # Get the input-lines as list
 ʒ                     # For-each over the lines to print using the filter-builtin:
  D                    #  Duplicate the current line
   4ú                  #  Prepend 4 spaces to this copy
     ".,?*&$@!%"       #  Push this string
                DÀ     #  Duplicate it, and rotate its copy once towards the left
                  ‡    #  Transliterate the space-prepended string with these two strings
                   «   #  Append it to the original duplicated line
                    ,  #  And print with trailing newlines
```

---

Here a version that also works in the new version of 05AB1E (credit to *@Grimy*):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
TFD?4ú".,?*&$@!%"DÀ‡,
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bY@xDcNACEX7myL4gAIhVoDCygRZIJFSJE2KLGB5k8ySTbzIhfNJrkLHA/7/vN7X2@Pe2uU8@7auz8nUhTGApvm7bMtHWzvtVY8afRksCMXYiGBMSqeASuyp5CYBnZekLAKKhBEeEszJSw1GTzcUUvNwCw6tpaqZGrI4IAaRiuR@FzHIYyOHTAlp0kV2S3Z0NlAHBhqWe0ANFA5RkiPgv3d@)

**Explanation:**

```python
TF                     # Loop 10 times:
  D                    #  Duplicate the (implicit) input-line
   ?                   #  Pop and print the copy without trailing newline
    4ú                 #  Prepend 4 spaces to the input-line
      ".,?*&$@!%"      #  Push this string
                 DÀ    #  Duplicate it, and rotate its copy once towards the left
                   ‡   #  Transliterate the space-prepended string with these two strings
                    ,  #  And print with trailing newlines
```

Comment: Non-legacy 21: `TFD?4ú".,?*&$@!%"DÀ‡,` (input is guaranteed to be exactly 10 lines).

Comment: @Grimy Will add it as well. Also found that `₂j` is a nice (although same byte) alternative for `4ú`, since the width is guaranteed to be 26 characters. :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
âìè╩Jù╠╕╜☻u$1∞;ⁿ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=838d8aca4a97ccb8bd02752431ec3bfc&i=++++++%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23++++++%0A+++%23%23%23%40%25%24*.%26.%25%25%21%23%23%23+++%0A++%23%23%21%24,%25%26%3F,%3F*%3F.*%40%21%23%23++%0A+%23%23%26**%21,%24%25%24%40%40%3F%40*%40%26%26%23%23+%0A%23%40%26%24%3F%40%21%25%24*%25,.%3F%40%3F.%40%26%40,%23%0A%23,..,.%24%26*%3F%21%24%24%40%25%25,**%26%26%23%0A+%23%23.%21%3F%40*.%25%3F%21*%26%24%21%25%26%3F%23%23+%0A++%23%23%21%26%3F%24%3F%26.%21,%3F%21%26%21%25%23%23++%0A+++%23%23%23,%40%24*%26%40*,%25*%23%23%23+++%0A++++++%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23%23++++++)

just a simple ring translation. Takes the input directly through STDIN.